# SSH Socks Proxy not changing public ip address

Tags: ssh-tunnel

Hey everyone I used the command

```
 ssh -D 9090 username@ipv4_address
```

I changed the proxy settings on firefox to the localhost 9090 but it doesn't
change the public ip address
I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and not using VM in case that helps
edit: I checked my public ip by googling "my ip" in case that helps. I believe that's your modem's ip address

Comment: How exactly do you check "the public ip address"?

Comment: googling "my ip"